# ACS dependency on SP2013 provider-hosted apps in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

While creating a provider-hosted app for SharePoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2013, in the app creation wizard on 'Configure authentication settings' page we have 2 options.
1) Use ACS
2) Use certificate(for on-premise)

Since I am using Azure as the host and I am forced to use ACS. Is it true? Is there any replacement for ACS for authentication in provider-hosted app in Azure?

I plan to change from Azure to on-premise at a later stage and I see this dependency on ACS annoying.

Answer (score 0):

We can Authenticate with out ACS(or any external authentication provider) by using AFDS(active directory federation service). Federation Server needs to installed in Intranet(AD already exists). The external party (app) gets autheticated through this federation server. No external(outside intranet) authentication mechanism is needed.