# Sharepoint 2013 auto-hosted app vs provider hosted app in Azure

Tags: sharepoint-2013

What is the difference between an Auto-hosted app in Azure and a provider-hosted app in Azure. 
Since both are hosted in Azure, can we say they are similar? Are there pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that with auto-hosted apps all Windows Azure and Windows Azure SQL Database components are provisioned for you when the app is installed and the Windows Azure Web Sites infrastructure handles load balancing and other important maintenance tasks for you. [1]

When using provider-hosted apps, you're responsible for provisioning what's necessary to support the app.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887.aspx#Autohosted

Comment: Okay, Auto-hosted=automatic provision of Azure & provider-hosted= manual provision of azure. But the load balancing and other maintenance support are same for both options since both are in Azure, is it not?

Comment: That is true. Even though you can build the same environment yourself using provider-hosting, the auto-hosted option saves you a lot of management and administration overhead. Another obvious difference is that auto-hosting only works with SharePoint Online apps. Using provider-hosting with Azure lets you integrate an on-premises SharePoint farm with app logic provisioned in Azure.

Comment: Thank you that is the answer I was looking for. One more question a bit deviating from the initial question. In such a situation (provider-hosting in azure) Can we do authentication with out using ACS? I have another question posted for this, you may please answer it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081783/acs-dependency-on-sp2013-provider-hosted-apps-in-vs-2013